# Bootstrap form helper: select option

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am currently building a form with Bootstrap form helpers and have trouble with the select option. Normally I would use  and when selecting an option I would simply add SELECT to the option. However, since this works with div's I have no idea how to select an option.

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox" data-name="type" data-name="type">
<div data-value="1" <?php $type ? "buyObject" : "SELECTED"; ?>>Option 1</div>
<div data-value="2" <?php $type ? "sellObject" : "SELECTED"; ?>>Option 2
</div>
<div data-value="3" <?php $type ? "brokerObject" : "SELECTED"; ?>>Option 3</div>
</div>
```

The above obviously doesn't work, but since I'm not an expert in front-end dev I have no idea how to accomplish the above.

Answer (score 0):

actually, your question is not understandable correct me if I'm wrong you don't want to use select dropdown right? then why don't you just add a dropdown with caret?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By having a quick look at the docs, you can't of course put `selected` on a list element, anyhow you have the `change.bfhselectbox` event available so you could change the appearence of the selected element from there however you like. The examples do that, so have a look at them.
Edit: I see they use an hidden input to maintain "state" about the selected value, this may help.